# Apple watch notification mirroring

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I'm trying to create a notification with an action on the Apple Watch. However the documentation is not really saying what is native and what should be made.

Currently I'm creating a UILocalNotification on the iPhone. However what I'm wondering is that the action button will be mirrored on the Apple Watch.

The code I'm using to create the notification on the iPhone is:

```
    let incrementAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    incrementAction.identifier = "OPEN_ACTION"
    incrementAction.title = "Open"
    incrementAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    incrementAction.authenticationRequired = false
    incrementAction.destructive = false

    let counterCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    counterCategory.identifier = "SLAGBOOM_CATEGORY"

    counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction],
    forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

    counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction],
    forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

    let types = UIUserNotificationType.Alert
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: NSSet(object: counterCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = message
    notification.category = "SLAGBOOM_CATEGORY"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Am I supposed to do anything to make sure the button will work on the Apple Watch? Or do I need to create a watchkit app only for a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get default notifications for free but the users only option is to dismiss it.

If you want something custom then you want to create your own watch target and build out the different notification views in the watch targets storyboard

Here's the [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1) on Apple's Watch Programming Kit the explains the different custom notifications you can make

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Sure let me know if you need any other examples

Comment: Well, I've searched some more but what I just found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265134/are-iphones-apps-notifications-going-to-be-triggered-on-the-apple-watch-by-defa Where it says that the background action will be visible on the Apple Watch. So if I only want a notification with actions I don't need a whole watchkit app?

Comment: @marc here's the page where apple explains the different ones https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1

Comment: That clears it up. Appearantly I already added the watch action support by adding it to the normal notification. Thanks again!